# Add new row with data entered to specific table on worksheet if certain listbox item selected

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

Using Excel 2013 VBA

I have a bit of code where I am looking for a new row of data to be added to the bottom of the tables of a worksheet. The worksheet that needs to be populated is Sheet3 ("Data Sheet") or just Data Sheet on the tab.

On the worksheet there are two tables (Table3 and Table4) and depending on the category selected from the listbox (called StatusListBox), the row of data is added to the bottom of either one of the two tables.

If the user selects "Live", "Secured" or "Completed" then Table3 should be populated but if the user selects "Tender (Pipeline"), Tender (Negotiated)" or "Tender (Favourable)" then Table 4 should be populated.

With the current code I have a new row of data is added to the bottom of BOTH Table3 and Table4.

```
Private Sub AddNewButton_Click()
Dim the_sheet As Worksheet
Dim table_list_object As ListObject
Dim table_object_row As ListRow
Set the_sheet = Sheets("Data Sheet")
Set table_list_objectA = the_sheet.ListObjects("Table3")
Set table_list_objectB = the_sheet.ListObjects("Table4")
Set table_object_rowA = table_list_objectA.ListRows.Add
Set table_object_rowB = table_list_objectB.ListRows.Add

If Me.StatusListBox.ListIndex = "Secured" Then
table_list_objectA.ListRows.Add
ElseIf Me.StatusListBox.ListIndex = "Live" Then
table_list_objectA.ListRows.Add
ElseIf Me.StatusListBox.ListIndex = "Completed" Then
table_list_objectA.ListRows.Add
ElseIf Me.StatusListBox.ListIndex = "Tender (Pipeline)" Then
table_list_objectB.ListRows.Add
ElseIf Me.StatusListBox.ListIndex = "Tender (Negotiated)" Then
table_list_objectB.ListRows.Add
ElseIf Me.StatusListBox.ListIndex = "Tender (Favourable)" Then
table_list_objectB.ListRows.Add
End If

table_object_rowA.Range(1, 1).Value = ProjectNameTextBox.Value
table_object_rowB.Range(1, 1).Value = ProjectNameTextBox.Value

last_row_with_data = the_sheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
last_row_with_data = last_row_with_data

the_sheet.Range("B" & last_row_with_data) = ClientTextBox.Value
the_sheet.Range("C" & last_row_with_data) = SectorListBox.Value
the_sheet.Range("D" & last_row_with_data) = StatusListBox.Value
the_sheet.Range("E" & last_row_with_data) = ContractValueTextBox.Value
the_sheet.Range("F" & last_row_with_data) = AFATextBox.Value
the_sheet.Range("G" & last_row_with_data) = RTPTextBox.Value
the_sheet.Range("H" & last_row_with_data) = TwentyFifteenTextBox.Value
the_sheet.Range("I" & last_row_with_data) = TwentySixteenTextBox.Value
the_sheet.Range("J" & last_row_with_data) = TwentySeventeenTextBox.Value
the_sheet.Range("K" & last_row_with_data) = TwentyEighteenTextBox.Value
the_sheet.Range("L" & last_row_with_data) = TwentyNineteenTextBox.Value
the_sheet.Range("M" & last_row_with_data) = DisciplineListBox.Value
the_sheet.Range("N" & last_row_with_data) = BoardDirectorListBox.Value
the_sheet.Range("O" & last_row_with_data) = AssociateDirectorTextBox.Value
the_sheet.Range("P" & last_row_with_data) = CommercialManagerTextBox.Value
the_sheet.Range("Q" & last_row_with_data) = ProjectManagerTextBox.Value
the_sheet.Range("R" & last_row_with_data) = QuantitySurveyorTextBox.Value
the_sheet.Range("S" & last_row_with_data) = PreConTextBox.Value
the_sheet.Range("T" & last_row_with_data) = ActualTextBox.Value
the_sheet.Range("U" & last_row_with_data) = DPStartTextBox.Value
the_sheet.Range("V" & last_row_with_data) = DPEndTextBox.Value

If Me.ProjectNameTextBox.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please enter Project Name.", vbExclamation, "Project Tracker Template"
Me.ProjectNameTextBox.SetFocus
End If

End Sub
```

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Your `set` statements (e.g. `Set table_object_rowA = table_list_objectA.ListRows.Add`) are, as they say, `Add`ing a row to the tables?  Also you might want to move the code checking `Me.ProjectNameTextBox.Value` further up the code, before you set the row value to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListIndex` property returns the item position inside the listbox list, while `.Value` property returns its selected value (if any) or an error (if no item selected)

So you may need something like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub AddNewButton_Click()
    Dim the_sheet As Worksheet
    Dim table_list_object As ListObject
    Dim table_object_row As ListRow
    Dim last_row_with_data As Long
    Dim tableName As String, errMsg As String


    If Me.ProjectNameTextBox.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter Project Name.", vbExclamation, "Project Tracker Template"
        Me.ProjectNameTextBox.SetFocus
    End If

    With Me.StatusListBox
        If .ListIndex <> -1 Then
            Select Case .Value
                Case "Secured", "Live", "Completed"
                    tableName = "Table3"
                Case "Tender (Pipeline)", "Tender (Negotiated)", "Tender (Favourable)"
                    tableName = "Table4"
                Case Else
                    errMsg = "No valid item selected!"
            End Select
        Else
            errMsg = "No item selected!"
        End If
    End With
    If tableName = "" Then
        MsgBox errMsg, vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set the_sheet = Sheets("Data Sheet")

    With the_sheet

        Set table_list_object = .ListObjects("Table3")
        Set table_object_row = table_list_object.ListRows.Add
        table_object_row.Range(1, 1).Value = ProjectNameTextBox.Value

        last_row_with_data = .Range(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1

        .Range("B" & last_row_with_data) = ClientTextBox.Value
        .Range("C" & last_row_with_data) = SectorListBox.Value
        .Range("D" & last_row_with_data) = StatusListBox.Value
        .Range("E" & last_row_with_data) = ContractValueTextBox.Value
        .Range("F" & last_row_with_data) = AFATextBox.Value
        .Range("G" & last_row_with_data) = RTPTextBox.Value
        .Range("H" & last_row_with_data) = TwentyFifteenTextBox.Value
        .Range("I" & last_row_with_data) = TwentySixteenTextBox.Value
        .Range("J" & last_row_with_data) = TwentySeventeenTextBox.Value
        .Range("K" & last_row_with_data) = TwentyEighteenTextBox.Value
        .Range("L" & last_row_with_data) = TwentyNineteenTextBox.Value
        .Range("M" & last_row_with_data) = DisciplineListBox.Value
        .Range("N" & last_row_with_data) = BoardDirectorListBox.Value
        .Range("O" & last_row_with_data) = AssociateDirectorTextBox.Value
        .Range("P" & last_row_with_data) = CommercialManagerTextBox.Value
        .Range("Q" & last_row_with_data) = ProjectManagerTextBox.Value
        .Range("R" & last_row_with_data) = QuantitySurveyorTextBox.Value
        .Range("S" & last_row_with_data) = PreConTextBox.Value
        .Range("T" & last_row_with_data) = ActualTextBox.Value
        .Range("U" & last_row_with_data) = DPStartTextBox.Value
        .Range("V" & last_row_with_data) = DPEndTextBox.Value

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Ignore this message. I started typing in the wrong space

Comment: @Nisaa Roberts: well, the code you posted as working is much the one I posted in this answer. Then, please mark this answer as accepted. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the issue with thanks to those that contributed.

I replaced .ListObjects("Table3") with .ListObjects(tableName)

This is the code that now works:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub AddNewButton_Click()
Dim the_sheet As Worksheet
Dim table_list_object As ListObject
Dim table_object_row As ListRow
Dim last_row_with_data As Long
Dim tableName As String, errMsg As String


If Me.ProjectNameTextBox.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please enter Project Name.", vbExclamation, "Project Tracker Template"
    Me.ProjectNameTextBox.SetFocus
End If

With Me.StatusListBox
    If .ListIndex <> -1 Then
        Select Case .Value
            Case "Secured", "Live", "Completed"
                tableName = "Table3"
            Case "Tender (Pipeline)", "Tender (Negotiated)", "Tender (Favourable)"
                tableName = "Table4"
            Case Else
                errMsg = "No valid item selected!"
        End Select
    Else
        errMsg = "No item selected!"
    End If
End With
If tableName = "" Then
    MsgBox errMsg, vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

Set the_sheet = Sheets("Data Sheet")

With the_sheet

    Set table_list_object = .ListObjects(tableName)
    Set table_object_row = table_list_object.ListRows.Add

    last_row_with_data = the_sheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

    table_object_row.Range(1, 1).Value = ProjectNameTextBox.Value
    table_object_row.Range(1, 2).Value = ClientTextBox.Value
    table_object_row.Range(1, 3).Value = SectorListBox.Value
    table_object_row.Range(1, 4).Value = StatusListBox.Value
    table_object_row.Range(1, 5).Value = ContractValueTextBox.Value
    table_object_row.Range(1, 6).Value = AFATextBox.Value
    table_object_row.Range(1, 7).Value = RTPTextBox.Value
    table_object_row.Range(1, 8).Value = TwentyFifteenTextBox.Value
    table_object_row.Range(1, 9).Value = TwentySixteenTextBox.Value
    table_object_row.Range(1, 10).Value = TwentySeventeenTextBox.Value
    table_object_row.Range(1, 11).Value = TwentyEighteenTextBox.Value
    table_object_row.Range(1, 12).Value = TwentyNineteenTextBox.Value
    table_object_row.Range(1, 13).Value = DisciplineListBox.Value
    table_object_row.Range(1, 14).Value = BoardDirectorListBox.Value
    table_object_row.Range(1, 15).Value = AssociateDirectorTextBox.Value
    table_object_row.Range(1, 16).Value = CommercialManagerTextBox.Value
    table_object_row.Range(1, 17).Value = ProjectManagerTextBox.Value
    table_object_row.Range(1, 18).Value = QuantitySurveyorTextBox.Value
    table_object_row.Range(1, 19).Value = PreConTextBox.Value
    table_object_row.Range(1, 20).Value = ActualTextBox.Value
    table_object_row.Range(1, 21).Value = DPStartTextBox.Value
    table_object_row.Range(1, 22).Value = DPEndTextBox.Value

End With

End Sub
```

Many thanks.